# Tower design engineering drawing

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering

I am trying to understand what the drawing states for a transmission tower.

Specifically, the underlined portion. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

BC65X31 + CO45
CT41X38
CO45

[image]

Comment: I would start with what part of the world were the drawings intended for.  The nomenclature for calling out steel shapes can vary depending where in the world you are.  [This nomenclature](http://www.draftsperson.net/index.php?title=Designation_or_codes_of_steel_members) from down under is probably very easy for an engineer in Australia/New Zealand but it a bit of a stretch from the system used in Canada or the US.